# Rasterize points by 'most frequent' in R

Tags: r, rasterization

I have a series of spatial data points that I want to convert to a raster using the R function rasterize. The data I want represented is a factor value, so I want to represent the most frequently occuring value for each raster cell.

I have tried to write a funtion to get the mode, but it fails.

```
getmode <- function(v) {
uniqv <- unique(v)
uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}
```

run rasterize

```
test <- rasterize(best, rast, best$val, fun = getmode)
```

results in this error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (na.rm = na.rm)
```

Answer (score 5):

`getmode` is called with two arguments in case you want to handle missing values in your custom function. Rewrite it to accept extra arguments:

```
getmode <- function(v,na.rm) {
uniqv <- unique(v)
uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}
```

that should fix that problem (and reveal the next one...)

Comment: Thank you! Next error is: 
    Error in setValues(rs, vv) : values must be numeric, integer, logical or factor
however, val is already a factor class. any ideas?

Comment: @Jack_daniels Please ask a new question for the "Next error".  That way we start to build another Q&A with another new clear question likely to result in another clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if useful at this stage, but could you do fun = modal